# Unique Constraint for Dates does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I setup the "unique" value for the **date** column
anyways, anytime I post a new object **with the same date** it lets it happen.

I know I could design the unique constraint directly in the database
but isnt it possible to do it here?

It is a REST application, I am Posting a JSON object like this:

```
'{
 "date":"2022-10-17"
 }'
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "daylife")
public class DayLife {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate date;
```

Comment: What database are you using and what type does the database column have?

Comment: @derkoe MySql database. datetime(6)

Comment: There you have it - it is a datetime(6) type - these are only uniqe if the have the same microsecond

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as I added the UNIQUE parameter in the class
AFTER the table as already created, I deleted the table
and Spring created it again and now it has the Constraint.